# Can we have two or more website hosted on a computer with IIS

Tags: networking, domain-name-system, iis-7, website

I have an Virtual machine which has R2 2008 with an website which just works fine. I was wondering if there's any way we could host multiple websites on that server. Since its virtual we can add couple nic's if we'd like so more IP's.

Any ideas how else we could achieve this ?

Thanks for replying and reading the question....

Comment: Yes you can do this easily but can I suggest yo get some IIS/Windows training as this is so basic that it's clear you need some help in understanding this, otherwise if you just follow instructions and don't truly understand what you've done you'll just be creating further problems down the line - does that make sense? I'm not trying to be horrible, just helpful.

Answer (score 1):

You do not need to add more IPs or network cards. Please read about host header recognition and virtual hosts. [This page may help.](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc753729.aspx)